# pandas - change values of second level index to display position within first level index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

How can I change the values of a second level index from

```
                           PRICE  
TIMESTAMP           HSEC                            
2013-03-15 09:00:29  1     34.480 
2013-03-15 09:00:30  0     34.470  
                     3     34.485  
2013-03-15 09:00:31  0     34.495   
2013-03-15 09:00:35  0     34.485   
2013-03-15 09:00:36 10     34.480  
                    65
```

to

```
                           PRICE  
TIMESTAMP           HSEC                            
2013-03-15 09:00:29  0     34.480 
2013-03-15 09:00:30  0     34.470  
                     1     34.485  
2013-03-15 09:00:31  0     34.495   
2013-03-15 09:00:35  0     34.485   
2013-03-15 09:00:36  0     34.480  
                     1
```

such that 'HSEC' displays the position of the row within the first-level index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with this data:

```
In [119]: df
Out[119]: 
                           PRICE
TIMESTAMP           HSEC        
2013-03-15 09:00:29 1     34.480
2013-03-15 09:00:30 0     34.470
                    3     34.485
2013-03-15 09:00:31 0     34.495
2013-03-15 09:00:35 0     34.485
2013-03-15 09:00:36 10    34.480
                    65    34.480
```

My approach would be to groupby the first level of indicies, and transform with `range` to get an array of positions within in each group.  Then, a list of tuples is built up to make a new MultiIndex.

```
In [120]: positions = df.groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: range(len(x))).values.ravel()

In [121]: new_index = [(timestamp, position) for ((timestamp, _), position) in 
     ...:                        zip(df.index, positions)]

In [122]: df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index)

In [123]: df
Out[123]: 
                        PRICE
2013-03-15 09:00:29 0  34.480
2013-03-15 09:00:30 0  34.470
                    1  34.485
2013-03-15 09:00:31 0  34.495
2013-03-15 09:00:35 0  34.485
2013-03-15 09:00:36 0  34.480
                    1  34.480
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of chrisb actually works fine. However, I have t odo this operation to a number of large dataframes. So speed matters for me.

I found a way that looks a lot uglier, but runs considerably faster.

```
runlength = np.array(df.index.labels[0])

runlength = np.append(0,np.diff(runlength))

runlength = np.append(np.nonzero(runlength),len(df.index))
runlength = np.diff(np.append(0,runlength))

cumrunlength = np.cumsum(runlength)
cumrunlength = np.append(0,cumrunlength)
mylabel = df.index.labels[0]
neworder = [x - cumrunlength[mylabel[x]] for x in xrange(len(mylabel))]

df.reset_index(['TIMESTAMP','HSEC'], drop=False, inplace=True)
df['newIndex'] = neworder

df.set_index(['TIMESTAMP','newIndex'],inplace=True)
```

First, I check where the label of the first level changes. The difference in the index where these changes occur give me length of each run, i.e. the number of rows for each unique 'TIMESTAMP' entry. The position is then determined by substracting from a continues index 0,1,2,...,n the cumulative length of the runs occured up to the respective position.

I am quite new to python and pandas. So I don't know how a proper speed comparison looks like. Using a simple start_time = time.clock() and print time.clock() - start_time, 'seconds', I found that the code of chrisb takes around 4 to 5 seconds, while the one above takes 0.04 seconds on a data frame of length 16325. My guess would be that this is due to the .groupby() operation that works like a loop. Would that be correct?